# First TS file is the biggest: ffmpeg mp4 to hls

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming

While converting mp4 to hls, ffmpeg makes the 0.ts file the biggest comparing to others. How to fix it?

[image: example]

This is running on a Linux server, running Debian 9, FFMPEG 3.2.12-1~deb9u1.

```sh
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -hide_banner -loglevel error -c copy -f hls -hls_time 7 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_size 5000000 output.m3u8
```

I expect to get all the `*.ts` files to be less than 8MB.